# Matrix.rotateM android API result in wrong rotating Matrix

Tags: math, matrix, graphics, opengl-es, rotation

I´m doing my own collada parser. When animating joints I have a list of ordered transformations to apply. When all them are applied, I get a matrix, the joint node matrix. I think is this way how it works.

The way this system works as far as I know is, in the first transformation, applying it to the identity matrix, and successively applying to the result matrix the next transformation until the last one.

Applying a translate transformation to a matrix looks to works ok, but when rotating it something strange is happening:

For example: the two first transformations are a translation and a rotation arround the z axis. This looks like this:

```
<translate> -0.6289 63.7555 0.008499979 </translate>
<rotate>0 0 1 -5.00881</rotate>
```

Using the Matrix.translateM and Matrix.rotateM android api functions I get this matrix:

```
storedMatrix  =

  0.9961813    0.0873089    0.  - 0.6289     
- 0.0873089    0.9961813    0.    63.7555    
  0.           0.           1.    0.0085000  
  0.           0.           0.    1.
```

Using SciLAB (it´s a free software to replace Matlab) I programmed a script to calculate a translate and a rotate matrix. This is the code I put into the script:

```
function [storedMatrix] = rotateStoredMat(x_axis,y_axis,z_axis,angle_amount)

    // t is angle amount, x is x_axis, and...

    // ESTA ES LA FÓRMULA (NO SACADA DE WIKIPEDIA PERO ALLI ESTA IGUAL) PARA MATRICES ORGANIZADAS POR COLUMNAS
    // FROM WIKIPEDIA: 
    // x*x * (cos(t) - 1) + cos(t)    x*y * (cos(t) - 1) + (z*sin(t))  x*z * (cos(t) - 1) - (y*sin(t))
    // x*y * (cos(t) - 1) - z*sin(t)  y*y * (cos(t) - 1) + cos(t)      y*z * (cos(t) - 1) + (x*sin(t))
    // x*z * (cos(t) - 1) + y*sin(t)  y*z * (cos(t) - 1) - (x*sin(t))  z*z * (cos(t) - 1) + cos(t)

    global storedMatrix;
    xx = x_axis * x_axis;
    xy = x_axis * y_axis;
    xz = x_axis * z_axis;

    yy = y_axis * y_axis;
    yz = y_axis * z_axis;

    zz = z_axis * z_axis;
    cost = cos(angle_amount);
    sint = sin(angle_amount);
    mat = [
        xx*(cost -1)+cost           xy*(cost -1)+(z_axis*sint)          xz*(cost -1)-(y_axis*sint)      0;
        xy*(cost -1)-z_axis*sint    yy*(cost -1)+cost                   yz*(cost -1)+(x_axis*sint)      0;
        xz*(cost -1)+y_axis*sint    yz*(cost -1)-(x_axis*sint)               zz*(cost -1)+cost               0;
        0                           0                                   0                               1;

    ];

    storedMatrix = mat * storedMatrix;

endfunction

function [storedMatrix] = translateStoredMat(x,y,z)

    global storedMatrix;

    mat = [
        1           0          0        x;
        0           1          0        y;
        0           0          1        z;
        0           0          0        1;

    ];

    storedMatrix = mat * storedMatrix;

endfunction

function [storedMatrix] = loadIdentity()
    global storedMatrix;

    mat = [
        1           0          0        0;
        0           1          0        0;
        0           0          1        0;
        0           0          0        1;

    ];
    storedMatrix = mat;

endfunction
```

Using this "helper" script this is the matrix i get:

```
   ans  =

    0.2920992    0.9563880    0.           60.791296  
  - 0.9563880    0.2920992    0.           19.224402  
    0.           0.         - 0.4158016  - 0.0035343  
    0.           0.           0.           1.
```

So, is my scilab script wrong? Am I applying the rotateM function in the wrong way ?
All I can say is that the bones and the joints are drawn in wrong positions, so I supouse I´m not calculating the them fine and that my scilab is giving me the right matrix to use.

Can you help me? Do you need some information more to evaluate this and give an answer? Please feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few reasons for the difference:

1. `rotateM()` takes an angle in degrees, while the script you wrote treats it as an angle in radians.
2. Your rotation matrix calculation does not match the formula I see on Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix). All the terms look somewhat different. For example, you use `(cost - 1)` everywhere the Wikipedia page has `(1 - cost)`.
3. Your rotation matrix looks transposed compared to what `rotateM()` produces.
4. When you use the `Matrix` functions, you're multiplying the two matrices in the reverse order compared to what you do with your script.

Comment: Thanks you! You helped me a lot! Cant vote you up because I have not enought reputation